# Azure Team Services TF14098 Access Denied Error AdminProjectRights

Tags: azure, azure-devops

While trying to learn how to use Microsoft Azure Team Services I seem to have locked myself out of certain permission or rights.

I am connecting to my Team Services account using Visual Studio 2015 update 1 and the connection to the repository goes fine and I can get to the Source Code.  Then I attempt go to the TEAM menu -> TEAM PROJECT SETTINGS -> SOURCE CONTROL in order to make some admin adjustments.  I click on the Source Control menu item and I get this following error.

[image: Access Denied permissions error]

I am figuring I messed some Security setting up back in Team Services security pages for this project and I need to re-add myself to a Group or adjust a setting.

Within the Project I added myself to the Project Administrators and it looks like all the Permissions have the value of ALLOW.

I also added myself as a member of the "Project Collection Administrators" group under the DefaultCollection, but that did not help either. Any thoughts on what the problem is?

EDIT:
I was asked about collection permission in the comment below here are my settings, they look fine.
[image]

Comment: The user account in the error is the same user account that you use to logon the Visual Studio Team Services? Are you using a Microsoft account or an Azure Active Directory?  AdminProjectRights are set on Team project level. By default the Collection Administrators have this setting as inherited. Can you check if nothing is explicitly set to deny?

Comment: Yes it is the same account I am logging into VSTS with.
I am using a Microsoft Account, and it is also the admin account for the Azure AD too.
Looks like collection administration permissions are good too.  Copying image into the post above.

Comment: Make sure your account have the "Edit project-level information" permission. And then try signing out and re sign-in from VS.

Comment: So it looks like it cleared up by itself.  So i am wondering if this is a timing issue with Azure.  Initially I restarted Visual Studio and rebooted too, but only when coming in the next day did I notice the difference and I had done nothing to the machine since the last go around of tweaks the day before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the user account under the Security tab to see which groups or teams this account belongs. And check whether there is Deny permission for these groups or teams.

Comment: I tried that and I have ALLOW for everything, but within Visual Studio IDE I still get the message box.  I also removed the account from every group but the PROJECT ADMINISTRATORS and still the same issue.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue on another client machine?

Comment: I replied above in a comment about resolution.